# CDATA XML is truncated while parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, sax, cdata

I'm using a SAX parser (on android) to parse an xml file from an WebService. On some elements the CDATA is truncated and not complete, e.g. the XML-file contains data like

```
 <name><![CDATA[Gölsder und Ginck GmbH]]></name>
```

and after parsing the xml file with

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
   throws SAXException {
   super.characters(ch, start, length);
   String text = new String(ch, start, length);
```

the text only contains "Gölsder und Gin" (the first 15 characters). I debugged it with eclipse and i see that the whole string is not contained in the "char[] ch" argument of the method. so the parsing itself seems to have an error

Comment: FYI, VTD-XML won't have this problem

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem, too. The thing is that the `characters()` method can be called multiple times on the same element. In your case, if you were to write this:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
   throws SAXException {
   super.characters(ch, start, length);
   String text = new String(ch, start, length);
   Log.d("XMLTEST", text);
}
```

You would probably get two log messages, one `Gölsder und Gin` and one `ck GmbH`.

In conclusion, you need to have member variables that you concatenate when receiving new characters.

Comment: I had the same issue and ended up concatenating it's weird though as it only sometimes splits the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is my work around after reading felix's post

```
private String text;

@Override
public void endElement(java.lang.String uri,
                       java.lang.String localName,
                       java.lang.String qName)
        throws SAXException {
       text = null;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    if(text != null){
        text += String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
    } else {
        text = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```